# EJB invocation failed: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm learning Java EE Development with the book Java EE7 Development with Wildfly. Now I encounter the Problem, if I want to run the example code I get the error:

**EJB Invocation failed on component TheatreBox for method public void de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.boundary.TheatreBox.buyTicket(int): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException**

Until now I can't fix the Problem and I have no idead what could cause this error. I already compared the example Code with mine, but no luck.

#### AutomaticSellerService

```
package de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.control;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.Timer;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.boundary.TheatreBox;
import de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.entity.Seat;

@Stateless
public class AutomaticSellerService {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;

    @Inject
    private TheatreBox theatreBox;

    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService;

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/30", persistent = false)
    public void automaticCustomer() {
        final Seat seat = findFreeSeat();

        if(seat == null) {
            cancelTimers();
            logger.info("Scheduler gone!");
            return;
        }

        theatreBox.buyTicket(seat.getId());  //I think this line causes the error

        logger.info("Somebody just booked seat number " + seat.getId());
    }

    private Seat findFreeSeat(){
        final Collection<Seat> list = theatreBox.getSeats();
        for(Seat seat : list) {
            if(!seat.isBooked()) {
                return seat;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void cancelTimers() {
        for(Timer timer : timerService.getTimers()) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

}
```

---

#### TheatreBox

```
package de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.boundary;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.AccessTimeout;
import javax.ejb.Lock;
import javax.ejb.LockType;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.entity.Seat;

@Singleton
@Startup
@AccessTimeout(value = 5, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public class TheatreBox {


  @Inject
  private Logger logger;

  private Map<Integer, Seat> seats;

  @Inject
  private Event<Seat> seatEvent;

  @PostConstruct
  public void setupTheatre() {
    seats = new HashMap<>();
    int id = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        addSeat(new Seat(++id, "Stalls", 40));
        addSeat(new Seat(++id, "Circle", 20));
        addSeat(new Seat(++id, "Balcony", 10));
    }
    logger.info("Seat Map constructed.");
  }

  private void addSeat(Seat seat) {
    seats.put(seat.getId(), seat);
  }

  @Lock(LockType.READ)
  public Collection<Seat> getSeats() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(seats.values());
  }

  @Lock(LockType.READ)
  public int getSeatPrice(int seatId) {
    return getSeat(seatId).getPrice();
  }

  @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
  public void buyTicket(int seatId) {
    final Seat seat = getSeat(seatId);
    final Seat bookedSeat = seat.getBookedSeat();
    addSeat(bookedSeat);

    seatEvent.fire(bookedSeat);
  }

  @Lock()
  private Seat getSeat(int seatId) {
    final Seat seat = seats.get(seatId);
    return seat;
  }
}
```

## EDIT 1

In `findFreeSeat()` I'm able to use `theatreBox` but when I try to use `theatreBox.buyTicket(seat.getId());` my application crashes. Removing this line also removes the error.

## EDIT 2

`seatEvent.fire(bookedSeat);` causes the problem inside `theatreBox.buyTicket(seat.getId())`

## EDIT 3

```
package de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.entity.Seat;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class BookingRecord implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int bookedCount = 0;

    public int getBookedCount() {
        return bookedCount;
    }

    public void bookEvent(@Observes Seat bookedSeat) {
        bookedCount++;
    }
}
```

## EDIT 4

### Seat.java

```
package de.wflydevelopment.chapter4.entity;

public class Seat{

    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final int price;
    private final boolean booked;

    public Seat(int id, String name, int price) {
        this(id, name, price, false);
    }

    private Seat(int id, String name, int price, boolean booked) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.booked = booked;
    }

    public Seat getBookedSeat() {
        return new Seat(getId(), getName(), getPrice(), true);
    } 

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public boolean isBooked() {
        return booked;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Seat [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", booked=" + booked + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to send an Event, but I'm not see your consumer (Observer) class? Did you already try to commented the `seatEvent.fire(bookedSeat);` and see whether the error still occur or not.

Comment: I update my question and added the class that should handle the Event. If I comment `seatEvent.fire(bookedSeat)` the error disappears.

Comment: Your consumer class look good, then what about this part `final Seat bookedSeat = seat.getBookedSeat();` on `buyTicket()` method? How did you return a booked seat? Since there is no logic on change from free seat into booked one.

Comment: I added the `Seat.java` to my question. It just returns a new `Seat` with the same properties, except that `booked` is set to `true`